# Multiple web api with same endpoint

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

In our solution we have multiple web api projects created and these are hosted on azure web app independently.Because of which each web api project has different url, like following

https://www.**xyz**.azurewebsite.net/api/employee/getemployee
https://www.**abc**.azurewebsite.net/api/department/getdepartment

Here Employee is one web api project and department is second one.

So my question is how can we host these web api under same webapp/domain on azure.

[image]
Because what has happened I have added blank api project with only web api method. I have made Set as startup project. and while pushing the code it has overridden other api project profile and after that the other api stopped working.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: `under same webapp/domain on azure` Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @Win whatever number of web api projects and there web api they should have same url. Right now its different like i have shown in the question Like https://www.xyz.azurewebsite.net/api/employee/getemployee 
https://www.xyz.azurewebsite.net/api/department/getdepartment. This xyz means my client/company name.

Comment: It all depends on how you create projects in Visual Studio and how you deploy them to Azure. Could you show the screen shot of VS solution?

Comment: @Win I have added the screen shot of VS solution.

Comment: Well, you have to two different projects. Without combing those two controllers into a single project, you cannot publish and access them via  same endpoint like you described. If you are aiming for microservices, you might want to look at API Gateway (Azure API Management).

Comment: @Win Ok. is it doable via API gateway ? Can you give me any link if you have

Comment: Azure API Management is nothing more than a facade/gateway. The correct platform for microservices is Service Fabric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if your application needs to display all employees for a given department? How will you solve that with your given setup? How will you be ensuring referential integrity across your department and employee stores? What you are designing is what I like to refer as **nano**services and are bound to have serious implications for your applications performance and scalability. HATEOUS in my experience falls apart when your domain is highly relational and there are no logical and evident boundaries. Considering what I can see in your code, you will be better off with 1 Web Api project with an Employee and Department controller. Consider microservices when you need to scale your services independent of each other or if there is a natural bounded context that can be inferred.

Comment: This was done purely considering micro services architecture. Though we haven't started on it. We also have CI/CD pipeline in place for APIs.

Comment: What if your application needs to display all employees for a given department? How will you solve that with your given setup? How will you be ensuring referential integrity across your department and employee stores? What you are designing is nanoservices and are bound to have serious implications for your applications performance and scalability. HATEOUS in my experience falls apart when your domain is highly relational and there are no logical and evident boundaries.

Comment: Ok That make send. So you are saying instead of multiple web api project, we should have one with multiple controllers. Because We were thining what will happen in case of authentication functionality ?

Comment: That is correct. I've updated my answer as well now that I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Please accept if it addresses your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can host two or more projects on the same Azure Web App by setting up multiple Virtual Applications. To do so:

1. Log into your Azure Portal and navigate to your Web App blade.
2. Click on the Application Settings menu option on your Web App.
3. Scroll to the bottom and define a new Application. "/" already points to your /wwwroot directory. You can define a virtual path of "/employee", set the physical path to "/employee", and set the Type to "Application".

When you publish your Employee web app, you'll need to make sure to append the virtual path to your Site name and Destination Url under the Publish -> Connection tab.

Note: since these are separate virtual applications, they will not share state.

Comment: Is this best practice ? I mean people are actually following this.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If both of your web applications are part of the same app and need to share state, then combining the controllers into one project is the cleaner approach. If you are trying to pack multiple web applications into a single Azure Web App in order to reduce hosting cost and increase density, then this is a good approach.